# highlight multiple map areas using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery

How to highlight multiple area of a map at the same time on mouse hover from an external link using jquery. The id of the area is dynamic from codebehind C#. Can anyone get me a sample?

```
<div id="map">
<map name="scandinavia_map" id="scandinavia_map">
 <area id="area_finland" shape="poly" coords="193,64,207,78,217,80,226,90,228,104,229,114,234,122,234,133,237,144,254,157,251,172,208,234,196,307,206,312,246,311,306,283,339,228,339,202,290,74,281,71,274,50,277,42,272,34,266,33,262,29,252,34,245,38,243,53,245,60,234,72,228,68,222,72,212,71,198,58,197,58,198,62"></map> 
<script>$("#map area").mouseover(function() {
        var alt_text = $(this).attr('alt');
        $("#test").html(alt_text);
    })</script> </div>
```

Comment: Your question is far too vague! How is your map rendered? what is your HTML structure? Your JavaScript? What have you tried so far?

Comment: <div id="map"><map name="scandinavia_map" id="scandinavia_map">
                    <area id="area_finland" shape="poly" coords="193,64,207,78,217,80,226,90,228,104,229,114,234,122,234,133,237,144,254,157,251,172,208,234,196,307,206,312,246,311,306,283,339,228,339,202,290,74,281,71,274,50,277,42,272,34,266,33,262,29,252,34,245,38,243,53,245,60,234,72,228,68,222,72,212,71,198,58,197,58,198,62" /map>                                          <script>$("#map area").mouseover(function() {
        var alt_text = $(this).attr('alt');
        $("#test").html(alt_text);
    })</script> </div>